# How to delete multiple rows in Sqlite Manager

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, sqlitemanager

i have a sql database, it contain 50.000 records but i want only 100 records.
it is very hard to delete it manually, so there is not a solution to delete it with SQl Commands (using SQlite Manager of Firfox)

Thank you

Comment: You have to filter what you want to delete and what's useless

Comment: Specify what differentiates the rows you want to keep from the rows you want to delete.

Comment: @Rekcs may be i didn't explained well, but my problem is the same of this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822135/

Comment: @CL. may be i didn't explained well, but my problem is the same of this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29822135/

Comment: And what is the problem with that answer?

Comment: didn't worked for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i've found my solution, its just simple condition code:

```
DELETE FROM `TABLE_NAME`
WHERE `id` > '100'
```

after you run this code, all rows which have id > 100 will be deleted.
you can change the condition as you want, like changing table name, condition name (in my case its "id"), and the condition "<" or ">"...

i hope its helpfull..!